# Difference between Content-Disposition: attachment and <a>'s download attribute

Tags: html, download, http-headers

When the response header of an HTTP request is `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.gif`, the response body is downloaded by the browser as **"image.gif"**. The same seems to be achieved when an anchor tag has the download `enter code here`attribute set to **"image.gif"**.

What's the difference between the two then? Is the `Content-Disposition: attachment` method no longer of much use in browsers that support the "`download`" attribute on anchor tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content-Disposition is still useful.

The download attribute will take precedence over the Content-Disposition for the filename:

> If the Content-Disposition header has different information from the download attribute, resulting behavior may differ:
> If the header specifies a filename, it takes priority over a filename specified in the download attribute.
> If the header specifies a disposition of inline, Chrome, and Firefox 82 and later, prioritize the attribute and treat it as a download. Firefox versions before 82 prioritize the header and will display the content inline.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download)

You do not have to use HTML5 download attribute however, so Content-Disposition is another way the server can decide the filename without client direction.

Also of note is that the download attribute only works same-origin, so it will not work without Content-Disposition attachment if the origins are different.